# UbuntuARM packages - where have they gone?

Tags: robotic-arm, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The namniart.com domain, which hosted ROS packages for Ubuntu / ARM devices at http://packages.namniart.com/repos/ros until recently, appears to have expired.

Does anyone know where the Ubuntu ARM packages (e.g. for installing ROS on Beaglebone Black, Radxa Rock, Odroid single board computers) are hosted now?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199644/ubuntuarm-packages---where-have-they-gone?/) by [tommytwoeyes](https://answers.ros.org/users/1653/tommytwoeyes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2014-12-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry; I missed the domain renewal email, and the domain expired. I'm working on getting it renewed. I don't have these hosted anywhere else, and I'm not aware of anyone else who has a mirror, so you'll just have to wait until I get my server back online.

See: http://answers.ros.org/question/199429/could-not-resolve-packagesnamniartcom/ and http://answers.ros.org/question/199410/unable-to-setup-sourceslist-arm/

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tommytwoeyes](https://answers.ros.org/users/1653/tommytwoeyes/) on 2014-12-17**:
Sorry man, that sucks. I've missed those before, too. Let me know if there's anything I can do to help you.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-12-17**:
I've renewed the domain and the DNS records are updated. It may take up to 24 hours for the DNS changes to propagate.